# Getting Warning like "Format not a string Literal and no format arguments"

Tags: objective-c, ipad

Am getting the above warning at NSAssert(bgTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid,nil) line. Am working on Xcode4.5.1 with IOS SDK6.0. If any one know the reason, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

["`NSAssert`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/NSAssert) is expecting a NSLog / printf style format string as it's second argument.  If you provide one (instead of "`nil`"), that warning will go away.